# logistic regression with 1L penalty

Tags: r, logistic, lasso

Can anyone tell me why I get the same values at the end for this logistic regression for x1-x3 and x1-x14? There are more variables in there so the outcome should change at least a bit right?

```
x <- model.matrix(y ~ .-1 + x1 + x2 + x3, data=FullData)
y <- as.double(as.matrix(FullData[, 1]))

# Fitting the model (Lasso: Alpha = 1)
set.seed(999)
cv.lasso <- cv.glmnet(x, y, family='binomial', alpha=1, parallel=TRUE, standardize=TRUE, type.measure='auc')

# Results
plot(cv.lasso)
plot(cv.lasso$glmnet.fit, xvar="lambda", label=TRUE)
cv.lasso$lambda.min
cv.lasso$lambda.1se
coef(cv.lasso, s=cv.lasso$lambda.min)


############################################################

x <- model.matrix(y ~ .-1 + x1 + x2 + x3 +x4 + x5 + x6 + x7
                  + x8 +x9 + x10 + x11 + x12 + x13 + x14, data=FullData)
y <- as.double(as.matrix(FullData[, 1]))

# Fitting the model (Lasso: Alpha = 1)
set.seed(999)
cv.lasso <- cv.glmnet(x, y, family='binomial', alpha=1, parallel=TRUE, standardize=TRUE, type.measure='auc')

# Results
plot(cv.lasso)
plot(cv.lasso$glmnet.fit, xvar="lambda", label=TRUE)
cv.lasso$lambda.min
cv.lasso$lambda.1se
coef(cv.lasso, s=cv.lasso$lambda.min)`
```

This is the function I used to generate data:

```
GenerateData <- function( seed )
{
  set.seed( seed )

  # generate X
  x1 = runif(1500, -2, 2)
  x2 = rnorm(1500, mean = 4, sd = sqrt(2))
  x3 = rnorm(1500, mean = 0, sd = 1)
  x4 = runif(1500, -2, 2)
  x5 = runif(1500, -2, 2)
  x6 = runif(1500, -2, 2)
  x7 = runif(1500, -2, 2)
  x8 = runif(1500, -2, 2)
  x9 = runif(1500, -2, 2)
  x10 = runif(1500, -2, 2)
  x11 = runif(1500, -2, 2)
  x12 = runif(1500, -2, 2)
  x13 = runif(1500, -2, 2)
  x14 = runif(1500, -2, 2)

  # generate Y
  eta = -1.5 + (1.5*x1) + (0.85*x1^2) - (0.20*x1^3) + (2.5*I(x2<0)) + I(x2>3) + (0.3*x3)
  pi = exp(eta) / ( 1 + exp(eta) )
  y = rbinom(1500, 1, pi)

  # combine data and split into training and test data
  full = data.frame(y, x1, x2, x3, x4, x5, x6, x7, x8, x9, x10, x11, x12, x13, x14)
  names(full) = c( "y" ,  paste( "x" , 1:14 , sep="" ) )

  return(full)
}

source( "GenerateData.R" )
FullData = GenerateData( 1035932 )
train = FullData[ 1:750 , ]
test = FullData[ 751:1500 , ]
```

Comment: You haven't provided any test data, so there's no way anybody can tell what is going on.  I don't think this is really a programming question in scope for Stackoverflow anyway.

Comment: Provided the data. Could you take another look? @thelatemail